# mysql_num_rows() not a valid resource - mysql_error() shows nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code.

```
    include("DBHeader.inc.php");
    include("libs/ps_pagination.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products P, Manufacturers M WHERE M.sManufacturerCode='$LC' AND M.iManufacturerID=P.iManufacturerID";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    echo $sql;

    $pager = new PS_Pagination( $conn, $sql, 3, 4, null );
    $rs = $pager->paginate();
    $num = mysql_num_rows( $rs ) or die('Database Error: ' . mysql_error());
    if ($num >= 1 ) {
        echo "<table border='0' id='tbProd' class='tablesorter' style='width:520px;'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Code</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th> &nbsp; </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";

        //Looping through the retrieved records
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
            echo "<tr class='prodRow'>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['sProductCode'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['sProductName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='ProdEdit.php?=" . $row['sProductCode'] . "'><img src='images/manage.gif' alt='Edit " . $row['sProductName'] . "' /></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody></table>";
    }
    else {
        //if no records found
        echo "No records found!";
    }
```

And instead of it giving me the data from the table, it spits out on the screen:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/nyksys/www/regserver2/search_results.php on line 37
```

`mysql_error()` is actually returning nothing at all, so I'm very confused as to what the error is.  The SQL when echo'd:

```
SELECT * FROM Products P, Manufacturers M WHERE M.sManufacturerCode='216E3ACAC673DE0260083B5FF809B102B3EC' AND M.iManufacturerID=P.iManufacturerID
```

I'm baffled here! Am I overlooking something simple here?

I've double checked my database information, I'm certain that isn't the problem.

EDIT-  I'm following the tutorial *[Paginating Your Data with AJAX and Awesome PHP Pagination Class](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/paginating-your-data-with-ajax-and.html)*.

Comment: We have no idea what your `$rs` variable contains...

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products P, Manufacturers M WHERE M.sManufacturerCode='$LC' AND M.iManufacturerID=P.iManufacturerID";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;
```

`$rs` is a MySQL result resource that you could use with `mysql_num_rows`.

```
$pager = new PS_Pagination( $conn, $sql, 3, 4, null );    
$rs = $pager->paginate();
```

Now it's not<sup>1</sup>!

```
$num = mysql_num_rows( $rs ) or die('Database Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

Oops!

---

<sup>1</sup> Or, if it is, [a] you didn't show us that in your question, and [b] the original query was entirely pointless.

Comment: That was partly the issue, I looked at the lib/ps_pagination.php file and took out "check to see if db connection is valid" chunk... and now it works perfectly!

Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the $rs variable

Answer (score 0):

My guess is whatever the `PS_Pagination` class is doing, it is not returning a MySQL resource.  You are overwriting your `$rs` resource variable with that object, and it ceases to be a valid resource, even if your query succeeds.

```
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;

$pager = new PS_Pagination( $conn, $sql, 3, 4, null );

// Use a different variable than $rs here.
$rs = $pager->paginate();
```